# добавление класса родителю при нажатии на дочерний элемент

Tags: jquery

```
$(this).parent().addClass('active');
```

Имеется список ul, внутри li c ссылками. По нажатию на ссылку должен добавиться класс родителю. Вроде все просто но почему то такой код не срабатывает. Он находится в функции, которая вызывается по нажатию, сама функция вызывается, ошибок не выдает, но и класс не меняет.
**UPD:**

```js
function change_content(id) {
  $('.left ul li').removeClass('active');
  $(this).parent().addClass('active');
}
```

```html
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change_content(1);">Продам <sup>1</sup></a>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change_content(2);">Куплю <sup>12</sup></a>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change_content(3);">Сдам <sup>11</sup></a>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change_content(4);">Сниму <sup>0</sup></a>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change_content(5);">Обменяю<sup>1</sup></a>
</li>
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change_content(6);">Отдам<sup>0</sup></a>
</li>
```

Comment: приведенный код корректен, добавьте пример функции которая его вызывает, а так же разметку на которой вы пробовали

Comment: @Vadim.K если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его решением(зеленая галка под цифрой слева от ответа).

Answer (score 4):

Как вариант можно сделать так:

```js
$(".test a").on("click", function() {
  //если нужно работать с параметром
  //var rel = $(this).attr("rel");
  $(this).parents("ul.test").find("li").removeClass("active");
  $(this).parent().addClass("active");
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="test">
  <li><a href="#" rel="1">Продам <sup>1</sup></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="2">Куплю <sup>12</sup></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="3">Сдам <sup>11</sup></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="4">Сниму <sup>0</sup></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="5">Обменяю<sup>1</sup></a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#" rel="6">Отдам<sup>0</sup></a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**UPD** - вариант с [closest()](http://jquery-docs.ru/Traversing/closest/):

*вместо `parents("ul.test")` можно использовать `closest("ul")`, в последнем случае поиск родителя будет идти до первого родителя `ul`*:

```
$(".test a").on("click", function(){
 $(this).closest("ul").find("li").removeClass("active");
 $(this).parent().addClass("active");
 return false;
});
```

Comment: мне кажется лучше _data-*_ атрибуты использовать вместо `rel`

Comment: @Grundy можно и так - это дело привычки.

Comment: И еще, вместо `parents` - лучше _closest_, так как _parents_ пойдет до конца вверх, а _closest_ до первого элемента соответствующего селектору

Comment: @Grundy да, можно использовать `closest`, но обычно каждому блоку страницы ставится уникальный класс или id, поэтому можно использовать `parents`. Добавили вариант с `closets()` для разнообразия.

Comment: Тут просто разница в том как работают эти две функции и класс или id тут ни при чем, _parents_ - **всегда** поднимается до самого верха и собирается всех предков подходящие по селектору

Comment: @Grundy подразумевали, что при помощи указания класса или id можно более точно найти конкретного родителя(что в принципе можно сделать и через индекс родителя, `parents("ul").eq(0)`) из всех. Разумеется принцип работы `parrents()` и `closets()` отличается, об этом мы написали в сноске к UPD.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34832/discussion-between-grundy-and-alex).

Answer (score 1):

При инлайновых обработчиках *this* указывает на глобальный объект, `window`, а не на элемент по которому кликнули.

Для решения:

1. Навешивать обработчики с помощью js, например

   ```
   $('li>a').click(change_content)
   ```

   и определять параметр который сейчас передается внутри, например по индексу кликнутого элемента.
2. Передавать сам элемент в функцию

   ```
   <li><a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="change_content(2,this);">Куплю <sup>12</sup></a>
   ```

   И поменять саму функцию:

   ```
   function change_content(id,elem) {
       $('.left ul li').removeClass('active');
       $(elem).parent().addClass('active');
   }
   ```